# Cannot Access Microcks URL installed on Minikube on Mac M1

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have installed the microcks based on the below URL. But the URL generated are not working.

Command used to install:

```
helm install microcks ./microcks --namespace=microcks \
    --set microcks.url=microcks.$(minikube ip).nip.io \
    --set keycloak.url=keycloak.$(minikube ip).nip.io \
```

Minikube IP:

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   43m
➜  microcks git:(develop) ✗ minikube ip 
192.168.49.2
```

url:https://keycloak.192.168.49.2.nip.io/auth

But the URL is not working from Local. Please guide me what is wrong here. I am new to K8S

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes version should be 1.17 or greater as the 1st requirement and it also assumes that you have some kind of kubernetes cluster up and running available.

Use below commands to install Microcks:

```
$ helm repo add microcks https://microcks.io/helm

$ kubectl create namespace microcks

$ helm install microcks microcks/microcks --version 1.1.0 --namespace microcks --set microcks.url=microcks.$(minikube ip).nip.io --set keycloak.url=keycloak.$(minikube ip).nip.io
```

Wait for few minutes and other components deployment you can retrieve the URL of the created ingress using:

```
kubectl get ingress -n microcks
```

You need to have keycloak component to configure the identity provider.

Also check this [video](https://youtu.be/u7SP1bQ8_FE) and [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12036)

Comment: thanks, Even after following this it did not work. Issue is with minikube on Mac M1. I was using rancher which solved my problem